# Nativescript - Hide Status Bar in Android

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript

I'm using Nativescript 7 and I'm trying to hide the status bar on android (The one with the clock, battery, etc... not the action bar).

So far I've found answers that seem to make it translucent.  I'm not interested in making it translucent as I'd like for it to disappear completely when the app loads.

At the moment I've used things like:

```
page.backgroundSpanUnderStatusBar = true;
```

But it simply makes the page content flow underneath the status bar (obviously).

Are there any ways to do this without a plugin?  If so, any code samples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you don't want to use a plugin? You can try [native-status-bar](https://github.com/PeterStaev/NativeScript-Status-Bar)

```
import * as statusBar from 'nativescript-status-bar'

statusBar.hide();
```

You can search for something similar, e.g. [nativescript-plugin-statusbar](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-plugin-statusbar/)

```
this.statusbar.hideStaturbar()
```

**If you need a solution without a plugin** you can try to use fullscreen flag:

```
const application = require('application').android
const activity = application.startActivity
const win = activity.getWindow()
win.addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't want a plugin because I figured it was small enough for me to maintain.  I try not to rely on 3rd party plugins when I can.